# ReactJS- unable to get the property from rowData on Action click handler in material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) in a react typescript project. I just copied the example code to my project, but it's not working because of some typings problems.The code is

```
export interface Entity {
    id:string,      
    name:string,
    abc:string,
    xyz:string
}
  const { totalCount, entities, listLoading } = currentState;  //currentState from useSelect

//recreating the Entities to make it mutable as I'm using redux-toolkit which freezes the state and and material-table don't accept freezed state objects
  const materialTableEntities=entities?entities.map((entity:Entity) => ({...entity})):[];

  // Table columns
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "ABC Column",
      field: "abc"
    },
    {
      title: "XYZ Column",
      field: "xyz"
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
    <MaterialTable
      title=""
      columns={columns}
      data={materialTableEntities}
      actions={[
        {
          icon: 'save',
          tooltip: 'Save Entity',
          onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.id)  //error on rowData.id
        },
        {
          icon: 'delete',
          tooltip: 'Delete Device',
          onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You deleted " + rowData.id)   //error on rowData.id
        }
      ]}
      options={{
        search: true,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1
      }}

    />
</>
```

Error is

> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string; abc:
> string; xyz: string; } | { ...; }[]'.

Comment: What's your `columns` and `materialTableEntities` looks like?

Comment: just as columns and data given in this example with different property names data properties accordingly. https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions

Comment: You can easily debug this by `console.log`ing the `rowData` before you do `rowData.id`.

Comment: I do that, but I think it's some typings issue. I just tried to pass the whole rowData object to another function and getting .id over there works fine

Answer (score 0):

fix by check type before , example :

```
if( !Array.isArray(rowData)){
   console.log(rowData.name)
}
```